# What can be the value of the determinant of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Suppose that the $ 3 × 3 $ matrix $A$ has an inverse and each entry of both $A$ and $A^{-1}$
is an integer. What can be the value of the determinant of $A$ ?

I did not understand that what it means that both $A$ and $A^{−1}$
have each entry an integer?

Comment: Did you mean to write $A^{-1}$ rather than $A−1$? You can typeset this as: `$A^{-1}$`.

Comment: Yeah Thank you edited!

Comment: No I meant I have edited it)

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. Punctuation can be confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that's meant to be $A^{-1}$, not $A-1$.  That is, all entries of both the matrix and its inverse are integers.

Hint: the determinant of a matrix of integers is an integer.

Comment: so can I say $det(AA^{-1})=det(A) * det(A^{-1})=det(I)$ and from that they both can be either $1$ or $-1$  ?

Comment: @subhanceo, Actually $|A^{-1}|=|A|^{-1}$ and that comes by the fact that $A\times A^{-1}=I$

Comment: I am waiting for @RobertIsrael to confirm my proof) then I will accept the answer

Comment: Yes, that is correct.